# PHP Autogenerate a record from a database

Tags: php, html, sql, database, web

I have a web base page where I want to generate records from my database one by one and at different time intervals. 
For example I have a table,

Comment

---

coment_id: 1 2 3 
comment_message: "Hello", "Hi", "Bye"

---

on the page, the first comment is Hello is posted then after 10 secs Hi is automatically posted then after 5 secs Bye is automatically posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally don't use PHP for that (nor you can really). Read about JavaScript and AJAX. In a nutshell, you make a PHP script to spit out a single comment, and then call it every 10 seconds using AJAX, it will spit out a comment every 10 seconds.

Comment: Can i use sql codes in javascript?? I have a vague knowledge about AJAX, just the Document.getelementbyid thing but still the core part is the timer.

Comment: No, AJAX is all about calling a page (as in sending a POST/GET request) without refreshing the page (which has nothing to do with `document.getElementByID()`). The timer itself will be initiated with `window.setInterval()`. May I suggest [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)? It's one of the best resources for web developers in general, and JavaScript developers specifically.